# Php multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have build this array structure from dig query data.

```
[10] => Array                      
    (                              
        [id] => 150                
        [0] => 200.201.202.23     
        [1] => dns.name1.com
        [2] => 200.201.202.24    
        [3] => dns.name2.com 
        [4] => 200.201.202.25     
        [5] => dns.name3.com
    )                              `
```

I need something like:

```
[10] => Array                      
    (                              

        [0]  => array ( [0] => 200.201.202.23     
                        [1] => dns.name1.com
                        [id] => 150 
               )
        [1] => array (  [0] => 200.201.202.24    
                        [1] => dns.name2.com 
                        [id] => 150 
                     )
        [2] => array (  [0] => 200.201.202.25     
                        [1] => dns.name3.com
                        [id] => 150  
                     )
    )                              `
```

I'm not sure if this is possible?

Heres the code where i create the array:
At the first time from the dig i use `array_push()` to add content to it.

```
$temp = array();
$i = 0;
foreach ($digResult as $single){
    if (preg_match('/(?:^|\s+)(\d+)(?:\s+|\n+|$)/', $single )){
        $temp []["id"]= $single;
        $i++;
    }else {
        $temp[$i][] = $single;
    }
}
```

Comment: Add the code where you build this array

Comment: Instead of creating here you should try to make it from there where you are creating first array.

Comment: Show the initial code, it can be changed to match the result.

Answer (score 1):

This will work for you :

```
<?php 
$dataArray = array(10 => array                      
                    (                              
                        'id' => 150 ,               
                        0 => '200.201.202.23' ,    
                        1 => 'dns.name1.com',
                        2 => '200.201.202.24', 
                        3 => 'dns.name2.com', 
                        4 => '200.201.202.25',     
                        5 => 'dns.name3.com',
                    ) 
                );    
$newArray = array();
$id = $dataArray[10]['id'];

for($i=0; $i< 6; $i++)
{
    $newArray[10][] =  array(0=>$dataArray[10][$i],1=>$dataArray[10][$i+1],'id'=> $id);
    $i+=1;
}
print_r($newArray);             
?>
```

This will output

```
Array
(
    [10] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 200.201.202.23
                    [1] => dns.name1.com
                    [id] => 150
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 200.201.202.24
                    [1] => dns.name2.com
                    [id] => 150
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 200.201.202.25
                    [1] => dns.name3.com
                    [id] => 150
                )

        )

)
```

***LIVE EXAMPLE : [CLICK HERE](https://eval.in/586768)***

Comment: you can accept my answer if it is helpful for you 

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
<?php

$array = array(                              
        'id' => '150',                
        '0' => '200.201.202.23',
        '1' => 'dns.name1.com',
        '2' => '200.201.202.24',
        '3' => 'dns.name2.com',
        '4' => '200.201.202.25',
        '5' => 'dns.name3.com'
    );

$i = 0;
$arrayLenght = (count($array)-2);
$newArray = array();
while ($i <= $arrayLenght) {
    $newArray[] = array(
            "0" => $array[$i++],
            "1" => $array[$i++],
            "id" => $array['id']
        );
}
echo '<pre>';
print_r($newArray);
echo '</pre>';
?>
```

Output:-

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 200.201.202.23
            [1] => dns.name1.com
            [id] => 150
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 200.201.202.24
            [1] => dns.name2.com
            [id] => 150
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 200.201.202.25
            [1] => dns.name3.com
            [id] => 150
        )

)
```